# How to make Eclipse formatter put a new line after arrays in a type annotation declartion?

Tags: java, eclipse, formatter

Say I have the following:

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;

@Entity
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery( name = "MyEntity.byUuid", query = "FROM MyEntity m WHERE m.uuid = :uuid AND m.isDeleted IS FALSE")
})
public class MyEntity extends AbstractEntity {

}
```

When I save this, Eclipse moves the closing `})` to the end of the `NamedQuery` line and it looks really dumb to have a `({` on its own line without the closing on its own line.

Is there a way to make eclipse stop moving that? I'd prefer to not put `formatter:off` there or anything silly like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the Eclipse formatter to control where new lines are added.

```
Window > Preferences > Java > 
        Code Style > Formatter
```

Press edit and go to braces tab

Choose braces style that you want for each.

Comment: I don't see any of those that apply to my issue.